# Updating EnvironmentObject in child view causes view to pop

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a child view that updates an EnvironmentObject that then causes the child view to pop back to its parent view. I am creating an app that uses similar "Like" functionality from this tutorial: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/letting-the-user-mark-favorites

Every time the like button is clicked and the EnvironmentObject likes object is updated, the view pops to the previous (ProductGridView) view instead of staying on the child view (ProductDetailView).

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var tabSelection = 0
@ObservedObject var products = Products()
@ObservedObject var favorites = Favorites()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            NavigationView{
                ProductGridView()
            }
            .tabItem { Image(systemName: "megaphone")
                Text("Products")
            }.tag(0)
             .environmentObject(products)
             .environmentObject(favorites)
     }


struct ProductGridView: View {
var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
@EnvironmentObject var products: Products
@EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites
var body: some View {
    VStack{
            ScrollView(.vertical,  showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(products.products, content: {
                            product in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetailView(product: product)) {
                                ProductCellView(product: product)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }.onAppear() {
                    self.products.fetchData()
                }
            }

struct ProductDetailView: View {
    let product: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack{
                ProductImageView(product: product)
                        Button(action: {
                            if favorites.contains(product) {
                                favorites.remove(product) //Updating here causes issue
                            } else {
                                favorites.add(product) //Updating here causes issue
                            }
                        }) {
                            if favorites.contains(product){
                                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                            }
                            else{
                                Image(systemName: "heart")
                            }
                        }
                    }

class Favorite : Identifiable, Encodable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
...

class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var products: [String]?
...

struct Product: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let productname: String
...
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't structure my model this way.  Create a single `ObservableObject` with `@Published` products and favourites.  Inject an instance of this model into the environment outside your view hierarchy (e.g. `ContentView().environmentObject(MyModel)`

Comment: Some observations, use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` in ContentView.
Is this the real code you are using or some half copy and paste job. 
I see "ProductView()" which you don't show, and do you declare "ProductGridView" 
inside your ContentView?

Comment: Also show how the contents of `products.products` (Presumable a `Product`) conforms to `identifiable` - Same for `Favorites`

Comment: I updated the question. I am only copying part of the code.

Comment: so Favorites is a class not a struct, or is it another half copy and paste?

Comment: Yes, Favorites is a class. This is only a half copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your fetch data call may be causing the issue.

```
struct YourContentView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection = 0
    @ObservedObject var products = Products()
    @ObservedObject var favorites = Favorites()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
                NavigationView{
                    ProductGridView()
                }
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "megaphone")
                    Text("Products")
                }.tag(0)
                .environmentObject(products)
                .environmentObject(favorites)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ProductDetailView: View {
    let product: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                
                Button {
                    if favorites.products?.contains(product) ?? false {
                        favorites.remove(product) //Updating here causes issue
                    } else {
                        favorites.add(product) //Updating here causes issue
                    }
                } label: {
                    if favorites.products?.contains(product) ?? false{
                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    }
                    else{
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProductCellView: View {
    @State var product: Product
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            Text(product.productname)
        }
    }
}


struct ProductGridView: View {
    let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
    @EnvironmentObject var products: Products
    @EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView(.vertical,  showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(products.products, content: {
                        product in
                      
                        NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetailView(product: product)) {
                            ProductCellView(product: product)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }.onAppear() {
                self.products.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
}

class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    @Published var products: [Product]? = []
  
    init() {}
    
    func remove(_ product: Product) {
        products?.removeAll(where: { $0.id == product.id })
    }
    
    func add(_ product: Product) {
        products?.append(product)
    }
}

class Products: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var products: [Product]
    
    init() {
        products = [.init(productname: "ApplePie"), .init( productname: "Cheeseburger")]
    }
   
    func fetchData() {
//        uncommenting this code will cause product grid view to reload because it relies on products
//        products = [.init(productname: "ApplePie"), .init( productname: "Cheeseburger")]
    }
}



struct Product: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let productname: String

    public static func ==(lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```